# Airflow - Dynamic Tasks and Downstream Dependencies

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I inherited the following dag which is running on AWS MWAA v2.2.2

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'test',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}

snowflake_conn_id='snowflake'

sources = [
    {'name': 'test_1', 'path': 'test1/path/'},
    {'name': 'test_2', 'path': 'test2/path'}
 ]

# define the DAG
with DAG(
    'test_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='test_dag test description.',
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1
) as dag:

    t0 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'start')

    for source in sources:
        create_table_sql = (
            f"CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE {source['name']} with location = @stage_dev/{source['path']} auto_refresh = true FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET);"
            )

        external_tables_from_s3 = SnowflakeOperator(
            task_id=f"create_external_table_for_{source['name']}",
            dag=dag,
            sql=create_table_sql,
            snowflake_conn_id=snowflake_conn_id
        )

    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'end')

    t0 >> external_tables_from_s3 >> t1
```

What is the best way to setupo this dag so that the external_tables_from_s3 tasks can be run in parallal

basically I want something like

```
to >> [create_external_table_for_test_1, create_external_table_for_test_2] >> t1
```

I was wondering what is the best way to achieve this without having to specify each task individually. The sources list is alot bigger than this and is just trimmed down for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple options depending on how you want to visualize the DAG in the UI:

1. Using a list to contain all of the `SnowflakeOperator` tasks, or
2. Use a `TaskGroup`.

**Option 1:**

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator


snowflake_conn_id = "snowflake"

sources = [{"name": "test_1", "path": "test1/path/"}, {"name": "test_2", "path": "test2/path"}]

# define the DAG
with DAG(
    "test_dag",
    default_args={
        "owner": "test",
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
    },
    description="test_dag test description.",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 2, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:

    t0 = DummyOperator(task_id="start")

    snowflake_tasks = []
    for source in sources:
        create_table_sql = f"CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE {source['name']} with location = @stage_dev/{source['path']} auto_refresh = true FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET);"

        external_tables_from_s3 = SnowflakeOperator(
            task_id=f"create_external_table_for_{source['name']}",
            sql=create_table_sql,
            snowflake_conn_id=snowflake_conn_id,
        )
        snowflake_tasks.append(external_tables_from_s3)

    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id="end")

    t0 >> snowflake_tasks >> t1
```

[image]

**Option 2:**

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup


snowflake_conn_id = "snowflake"

sources = [{"name": "test_1", "path": "test1/path/"}, {"name": "test_2", "path": "test2/path"}]

# define the DAG
with DAG(
    "test_dag",
    default_args={
        "owner": "test",
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
    },
    description="test_dag test description.",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 2, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:

    t0 = DummyOperator(task_id="start")

    with TaskGroup(group_id="snowflake_tasks") as snowflake_tasks:
        for source in sources:
            create_table_sql = f"CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE {source['name']} with location = @stage_dev/{source['path']} auto_refresh = true FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET);"

            external_tables_from_s3 = SnowflakeOperator(
                task_id=f"create_external_table_for_{source['name']}",
                sql=create_table_sql,
                snowflake_conn_id=snowflake_conn_id,
            )

    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id="end")

    t0 >> snowflake_tasks >> t1
```

[image]

Comment: I like the task group - I was not aware of this - this will work for me - thank you @josh-fell

Comment: @Damien Right on! This is a pretty good intro guide on TaskGroups if you want to peruse: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/task-groups/